# Android - ItemDecoration sometimes gone or misplaced while adding item or scrolling

Tags: android

I have just started using `ItemDecoration`. I am trying to achieve a divider in the middle of a two-column `RecyclerView` managed by `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`.

Here's my `ItemDecoration` code :

```
public class LobbyItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private int margin;
    private Drawable drawable;

    public LobbyItemDecoration(int margin, Drawable drawable){
        this.margin = margin;
        this.drawable = drawable;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);

        StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams lp = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams)view .getLayoutParams();
        int spanIndex = lp.getSpanIndex();

        if(position >= 0){
            if (position < ((LobiAdapter)parent.getAdapter()).getmDataset().size()){
                if(spanIndex == 1){
                    outRect.left = margin;
                    ((LobiAdapter)parent.getAdapter()).getmDataset().get(position).left = false;
                } else {
                    outRect.right = margin;
                    ((LobiAdapter)parent.getAdapter()).getmDataset().get(position).left = true;
                }
                outRect.bottom = margin;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        if (drawable == null) { super.onDrawOver(c, parent, state);return; }

        if(parent.getItemAnimator() != null && parent.getItemAnimator().isRunning()) {
            return;
        }

        final int top = parent.getPaddingTop();
        final int bottom = parent.getHeight() - parent.getPaddingBottom();
        final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();

        for (int i=1; i < childCount; i++) {
            final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
            StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams lp = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams)child .getLayoutParams();
            int spanIndex = lp.getSpanIndex();
            int size = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            final int ty = (int)(child.getTranslationY() + 0.5f);
            final int tx = (int)(child.getTranslationX() + 0.5f);
            final int leftIndex1 = child.getLeft() - (margin * 4 / 3) - tx;
            final int rightIndex1 = child.getLeft() - (margin * 2 / 3) - tx;
            final int leftIndex0 = child.getRight() + (margin * 2 / 3) + tx;
            final int rightIndex0 = child.getRight() + (margin * 4 / 3) + tx;
            if(spanIndex == 1){
//                drawable.setBounds(100, top, 5, bottom);
                drawable.setBounds(leftIndex1, top, rightIndex1, bottom);
                drawable.draw(c);
            } else {
                drawable.setBounds(leftIndex0, top, rightIndex0, bottom);
                drawable.draw(c);
//                drawable.setBounds(5, top, 100, bottom);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is as title said, whenever I load new item or scroll, the decoration is sometimes gone or misplaced. By gone I mean, literally gone, it's not there anymore until I scroll down or up to recycle the `View`.

And by misplaced I mean, when I scroll down, and the loading `ViewHolder` is in the left column, the divider "sticks" to the left column. If the loading `ViewHolder` is in the right column, it is normal.

Just in case : I use a `ViewHolder` to be a progress indicator by adding one null item and check it in `getItemViewType()` then remove it later after finishing the load from server.

This is how I add :

```
for (PostModel postModel :
        dataSet) {
    this.mDataset.add(postModel);
    notifyItemInserted(mDataset.size() - 1);
}
```

Comment: How did you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

StaggeredGridLayoutManager is buggy. For me this helped:

```
  diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
  recyclerView.postDelayed(() -> {
        layoutManager.invalidateSpanAssignments(); // to fix first item in second column issue
        recyclerView.invalidateItemDecorations(); // to fix wrong spacing
  }, 50);
```